# pyautogui でインストーラーに対するマウスクリック操作ができない

Tags: python, pyautogui

表題の件につきまして質問をさせていただきたいです。

#### 状況

インストーラーファイル(.exe/.msi)を開いた状態で、セットアップを自動化できないかと思い、Pythonのモジュールであるpyautoguiを用いてクリック操作するようプログラムを作ってみたのですが、クリック操作が反応しない現象が発生し対応に困っている状況です。

#### 現在の挙動・エラー内容

・locateOnScreen()で指定したクリックの対象にマウスカーソルが移動されているのは確認できている。
→ただなぜかクリックしてくれない。
・インストーラー以外のファイル(例:Microsoft Edge)はクリック操作等問題なくできていることが確認できている。
・click()した時の戻り値を確認したらNoneと出てきてしまう。
・pyファイルを実行した際、エラーが出てこないので画像認識自体できていないのかが判別つかない

#### 試したこと

・そもそもコーディングに誤りがある可能性もあるので、別のアイコンをクリックする処理を実装してみた。
→問題なくクリックすることができた。
・認識対象の画像が悪い可能性があるため、キャプチャしなおした
・locateOnScreen()の引数にconfidenceを導入しているため、精度の調整を図った。
・locateOnScreen()からclick()まで、たまに認識が間に合わずクリック操作が空回りすることがあるため、間にtime.sleep(1)を設け余裕を持たせた。
・対象のインストーラはマウスクリックで進めるほか、キー入力でも進めることができるので(「次へ(N)」みたいに)、
click()をhotkey('alt', "n")に変更した。

→これら試してみましたが、いずれもNGでした。

今回サンプルで用意したインストーラーはCubePDFになるのですが、
pyautoguiではこのようなインストーラーの操作はそもそもできないようになっているのでしょうか？
関連する記事がなかったものでして、原因が何なのかわからなくなってしまいましたので、ぜひとも皆様のお力を頂戴したく存じます。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
#モジュールインポート
import time
import pyautogui as pag

def main():
    try:
        #CubePDF
        event = pag.locateOnScreen([クリック対象のキャプチャファイルパス(絶対パスで指定しています。パスの直前にrを入れてます。)])
        time.sleep(1)
        pag.click(event)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: 別の方法としてインストーラがサイレントインストールモードをサポートしている場合があります。使っているソフトのヘルプを調べるとかサポート窓口に問い合わせてみてください。[ソフトウェアのサイレントインストールをしてみる。](https://www.alt-plus.jp/archives/1354), [msiexec](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec), [付録B. InstallShield コマンド行パラメーター](https://www.ibm.com/docs/ja/personal-communications/6.0?topic=guide-installshield-command-line-parameters), [サイレントインストール（無人インストール）について](https://www.miraclejob.com/recommend/detail?cd=816), [Setup Command Line Parameters](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline)

Comment: [管理者権限で実行](https://helpx.adobe.com/jp/x-productkb/global/230789.html)したPowershellなどでpythonスクリプトを実行し、NGであればさらに[UACを無効化](https://www.pasoble.jp/windows/10/08883.html)しても同様にNGでしょうか。

Comment: @kunif さん
ご提示いただいた情報で、Setupコマンドのパラメータを確認しサイレントインストールを実施することができました。他のexe/msiも未検証ではありますが同様に/help等でSetupパラメータを確認して実装していきたいと思います。

Comment: 想定していたものと違っても一応解決したなら、どのように解決したか/考え方を変更したか等を自己回答としてみてください。

Answer (score 1):

pyautoguiだとモノによっては反応しないようですので(動作確認済み)
・[setupコマンド](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline)
もしくは
・[powershellを使用したsendkeysクラス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)
この2つを使用し、サイレントインストール/GUI操作の自動化を実装しました。